# Sample CloudFormation template for deploying from dev to test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I read there are sample CloudFormation templates for deploying from Dev to Test env. The AWS resources are S3 bucket and Cloud-front Distribution. Does anyone know of a good sample template I could use? I looked at several Github but could not find any.